# Disposing components injected via constructor without lifetime scopes in Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-injection, autofac

I can't understand why my components never get disposed/released in Autofac.
I have a standard WPF application, which starts in app.xaml.cs resolving the `MainVM` which is a singleton and showing the `MainWindow` with `DataContext` of `MainVM`.

Then I work mainly with constructor injection of my registered components, which are singletons or (default) `instancePerDependency`, created new every time being injected. Or I have sometimes factories to pass some custom parameters.

For example, factories look like this:

```
public delegate MyComponent Factory(string parameter1, int parameter2);
```

Injection looks like this:

```
public MainVM(MyComponent.Factory createMyComponent)
...
public void makeNewComponent()
{
  var myComponent = this.createMyComponent("test", 1);
  myComponent.DoStuff();
}
```

And this is how my components are registered:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<T>().OnActivated(args => (args.Instance as IInitializable)?.Initialize());

builder.RegisterType<MyComponent>().As<IMyComponent>().OnActivated(args => (args.Instance as IInitializable)?.Initialize());

// This will never be called in my code: .OnRelease(instance => (instance as IInitializable)?.Uninitialize())*/;
```

Now let's image I have many such view models that are created inside other view models, so we have like `MainVM` -> `MyComponent` -> `OtherComponent`, and after an operation completes I want them to dispose (or just to disappear somehow from memory), to call `Dispose()` or to call the `OnRelease` event from Autofac. Any of these would do.

But my problem is - I am not using this pattern:

```
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
```

'Cause I am not working inside one method from { to }. I need my component to live inside an object in many methods, and after, say, I remove `ViewModel1` from my view stack, I want everything created inside this `ViewModel1` to dispose/release its children. What causes components to think they can be disposed? How can I tell a viewmodel it's not needed anymore, if it's not created inside a lifetime scope?

Answer (score 0):

You should not care about classes that don't implement `IDisposable`. Even though their instances are created by the Autofac container, the objects will be automatically GCed as soon as there will be no GC-rooted references to them (e.g. a view is closed and all references to it are `null`-ed). This affects the whole dependency graph - it doesn't matter how deep it is.

If you *do* have `IDisposable` objects in your setup, the container will of course hold references to them, because it needs to dispose of those objects. However, you still can control how this happens.

You can use the `Owned<T>` instances of your `IDisposable` dependencies for that.

Consider your example:

```
class MainVM 
{
    private readonly Owned<IMyComponent> _myComponent;

    public MainVM(Owned<IMyComponent> myComponent) => _myComponent = myComponent;

    public void DoStuff() => _myComponent.Value.DoStuff();

    public void OnViewClosed() => _myComponent.Dispose();
}

class MyComponent : IMyComponent, IDisposable
{
    public MyComponent(IOtherComponent otherComponent) { /* ... */ }
}

class OtherComponent : IOtherComponent, IDisposable
{
}
```

Now, when the `OnViewClosed` method gets called, the owned instance of `MyComponent` will be disposed of, *including all of `MyComponent`'s non-shared, disposable dependencies* - that is `OtherComponent` in our example.

Consider reading about the [owned instances](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/owned-instances.html) in the docs.

Comment: Unfortunately I still dont understand why OnRelease event is never called. Here is one more sample:

`//function starts`
`var vm = createMyVM();`
               `var wnd = viewFactory.ResolveWindow(vm);`
             `if (wnd.ShowDialog() == true)`
             `{`
               `//do stuff`
               `}`
`//function ends`


As I understand after leaving this function scope my VM and Window are no longer needed. But the VM never gets disposed/released :(

Comment: As far as I can see the code of Autofac - there is a line while resolving a component:
`e.Context.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>().Disposer.AddInstanceForDisposal((IDisposable) releaseAction1);` Doesnt it mean that he NEEDS a lifetimescope to track, otherwise he gets the global one and it never gets disposed?

Comment: `OnRelease` will only be called for lifetime-scoped objects. You don't use the scopes, so you don't get the method called. Owned objects don't need lifetime scopes. You control the scope manually by `Owned<T>.Dispose()`.